# need to improve bash regexp

Tags: regex, bash

in my bash script I use a regexp to match a string of variable assignment,
for instance:

1. Var = Value
2. var = Value;
3. Var=Value
4. Var=Value;
5. Var Value

the regexp i developed: `\s*${varName}\s*\={0,1}\s*.*\s*;{0,1}`

this regexp can match every instances above but also another instance that I don't want, which is **VarValue**

I cannot think of a way to make my regexp to not match the **VarValue** instance.

Comment: The rationale of the answers (and of an answer I was thinking of posting) is that you take match the "var" particle, case insensitive, then at least one whitespace or equal sign, then another word. There are escaped sequences (or POSIX classes) for detecting "words" and word boundaries.

Comment: Bash regex uses ERE, which \s wouldn't work with. Are you using `grep -P` in bash instead of bash's builtin regex?

Comment: @jordanm yes, I use `egrep` to match the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying yours:

```
\s*${varName}(\s?[\s\=]\s?).+\s*;{0,1}
```

Comment: You could also replace the final `{0,1}` with a `?`.

Comment: @Elias ` *${varName}( *[ \=] *).* *;{0,1} *` this work, replacing `\s` with just a space

Comment: @user990106 the `\s` was created to matches any space character, like tab, white space, new line... but if you always get ` `, it works!

Answer (score 2):

`\s*{varName}(?:\s*=\s*|\s+)(\w+)`

I didn't modify your regex since it seemed quite complicated for the job, but this one will match all cases listed above while not matching `VarValue`. Your data will be in group 1.

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?3196j).